# YII2 Hide dates from kartik-v calendar

Tags: calendar, yii2

I am using kartik-v extension in YII2.

```
<?php
    echo $form->field($model, 'dob')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter Bithday ...','readonly' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
                    'autoclose'=>true,
                    'endDate' => date('yyyy-M-d'),
                    'format' => 'yyyy-M-d',
                    ]
            ])->label(false);

?>
```

I want to allow user to select only date older than 18 years. 
How can i disable 18 years back dates from calendar from current year ?

Comment: use `yearRange` or set `minDate`.

Comment: try this `'maxDate'=> '-18Y',` in your `'pluginOptions'`